# Actionscript3, dynamic text, loop, xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have 6 dynamic text fields & I want to add text in them from an xml file.

This code works:

```
titleTxt1.text = xmlListMain.children()[0].title;
```

But in a loop there is a problem:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < xmlListMain.children().length(); i++) {
    titleTxt[i].text = xmlListMain.children()[i].title
}
```

`titleTxt[i].text`  is the part i get the error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your first textfield is named **titleTxt0.text** (ie your numbering starts with **0**):

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < xmlListMain.children().length(); i++) {
    this['titleTxt' + i].text = xmlListMain.children()[i].title;
}
```

if your first textfield is named **titleTxt1.text** (ie your numbering starts with **1**):

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < xmlListMain.children().length(); i++) {
    this['titleTxt' + (i + 1)].text = xmlListMain.children()[i].title;
}
```

Better to start your numbering with 0 for things like this so you can omit the extra step of adding 1 to the loop's index.

Comment: thank you for your help. i had to change the code a bit but it worked: this["titleTxt" + i].text

Comment: Yup, I should have put titleTxt in quotes.  Sorry about that, glad you caught it!  I edited the answer so others don't get misled.